# UIWebView strange behavior

Tags: uiwebview

I have a strange problem, 
http://tmskiosk.oneclick.info/sso/userauth.aspx

this link I open in browser works fine but when I open it in webview it is not loading it's css file (Probably).

`NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://tmskiosk.oneclick.info/sso/userauth.aspx"];`

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    //URL Requst Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]
```

`[siteWebView loadRequest:requestObj];`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below method.

```
WebView loadHTMLString:<#(NSString *)#> baseURL:<#(NSURL *)#>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Load web view data
    NSString *strWebsiteUlr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://tmskiosk.oneclick.info/sso/userauth.aspx"];

    NSString *escapedUrlString = [strWebsiteUlr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // Load URL

    //Create a URL object.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedUrlString];

    //URL Requst Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [_webview loadRequest:requestObj];
```